# Cannot add component to another package because it is installed so how else to move metadata without data loss?

Tags: salesforcedx, package, unlocked-package, package-dependency

I am trying to take out 3rd party libraries from a large monolith package called package M. These libraries are FFLIB, ApexMocks, ForceDI, and At4DX. Package M also has some code that references these open source libraries.

**Step 1**: I move FFLIB, ApexMocks, ForceDI, and At4DX to a new folder called 'doNotDeploy' in Package M. I then update my Package M sfdx-project.json with the following:

```
"unpackagedMetadata": {
            "path": "doNotDeploy"
        }
```

The step above because Package M has other code that depends on the libraries above.

I then create a package version (Version 04t6R0000011OkGQAU)

**Step 2**: I create a third-party-lib package (Package O) and move FFLIB, ApexMocks, ForceDI, and At4DX in it. I then create a package version (04t6R0000011OmCQAU) of this new package. No problems so far

**Step 3**: I go back to Package M and update the sfdx-project.json to:

a). Add a dependency to the new package O that I created

```
"dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "third-party-lib@1.0.0-3"
                }
```

b). Also remove the doNotDeploy folder and the following setting from sfdx-project.json

```
"unpackagedMetadata": {
            "path": "doNotDeploy"
        }
```

I then create a package O version successfully (Version 04t6R0000011OmHQAU)

**Step 4**:
**Executing the plan**

a). **INSTALL PACKAGE M (All Good)**
sfdx force:package:install --package 04t6R0000011OkGQAU -u mydx-org --publishwait 20 --wait 10 --apexcompile package -t DeprecateOnly

b). **INSTALL THE NEW THIRD PARTY LIB PACKAGE O (FAILING)**
sfdx force:package:install --package 04t6R0000011OmCQAU -u mydx-org --publishwait 20 --wait 10 --apexcompile package -t DeprecateOnly

CANT GET TO STEP C BELOW

**c). FINALLY INSTALL THE NEW PLATFORM PACKAGE WITH PROPE DEPENDENCY ON THIRD-PARTY-LIB**
sfdx force:package:install --package 04t6R0000011OmHQAU -u mydx-org --publishwait 20 --wait 10 --apexcompile package -t DeprecateOnly

I now get on step 2 above:

```
1) Cannot add component of type:ApexClass named:di_ModuleTest subjectId:01p1C0000087rND to another package because it is an installed component., Details: package.xml: Cannot add component of type:ApexClass named:di_ModuleTest subjectId:01p1C0000087rND to another package because it is an installed component.

ERROR running force:package:install:  Installation errors:
1) Cannot add component of type:ApexClass named:di_ModuleTest subjectId:01p1C0000087rND to another package because it is an installed component., Details: package.xml: Cannot add component of type:ApexClass named:di_ModuleTest subjectId:01p1C0000087rND to another package because it is an installed component.
```

I was hoping that the above error would not happen so that I could as a final step install (Version package-0-2) which would have the right dependencies but cant get to that point.

How to proceed and what are my options here? Clearly I put too much faith on Specify [Unpackaged Metadata for Package Version Creation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_path_unpackaged_md.htm&type=5&release=228).

Comment: You need to install the version with the unpackagedMetadata successfully before you can install the third-party lib. I'm not sure if you've actually tried that, because the version numbers are kind of weird.

Comment: I added the version numbers. @sfdcfox My step 4 A above did install just fine. Step 4 b above fails with that error.

Comment: Given your current position, do the items that you're trying to move appear as "deprecated" in the UI, or do they still appear as part of the package? Also, if I remember correctly, if you go to the package in the UI, you should be able to manually remove components? I think I saw this recently, and it may help.

Comment: Anything I had listed under unpackagedMetadata shows up on the UI as Unlocked - Installed. Are you saying after step 4a I manually remove the components from UI @sfdcfox ?

Comment: I'd recommend you give it a shot. I haven't had a chance to try it, but it sounds promising.